# I can't start project on Netbeans

Tags: netbeans

When I set name and location of a new Java project it stops and show a message of error :

```
A java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError exception has occurred
```

So the project isn't created and I can write any code lines on Netbeans.

**My OS version**

- Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS 64 bit

**My NetBeans version**

- Product Version: NetBeans IDE 7.0.1 (Build 20121011-unknown-revn)
- Java: 1.7.0_75; OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 24.75-b04
- System: Linux version 3.13.0-49-generic running on amd64; UTF-8; it_IT (nb)
- Userdir: /home/ema/.netbeans/7.0

Comment: Post the exception.

Comment: @A.B. He has already posted the exception `A java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError exception has occurred`

Comment: Have you set `classpath` in ~/.bashrc and `/etc/profile` . The error shows that it cannot find class definitions. And the predefined class definitions are located in `classpath`

Comment: @Faizan, that is only a part of the complete ecxeption.

Comment: Check [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/186693/how-set-classpath-variable-for-a-folder-in-ubuntu) for setting up classpath in ubuntu.

Comment: @Faizan I can't understand what and how i have to set up

Comment: i am adding an answer , please wait

Comment: @A.B. I didnt use `gksudo` since it doesn't allow `gedit` on some systems including mine and `gksudo` has to be installed first as it is not installed by default. Moreover the OP is a new linux user as seems from his comments, it may become difficult for him to comprehend all stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up CLASSPATH in `/etc/environment`. Execute the following command in a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>)

```
 sudo gedit /etc/environment
```

Add the following lines (all four lines at the end of /etc/environment)

```
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin"
export JAVA_HOME
CLASSPATH="/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/lib"
export CLASSPATH
```

Then restart your system.

Comment: In the terminal after  i run the first line( sudo gedit /etc/environment
) and add this JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin" I see this message:                                                                                                                  (gedit:3222): Gtk-WARNING **: Calling Inhibit failed: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files

Comment: No problem, just save the file and restart system. It should work now. Ignore these messages

Comment: nothing changes and when I run the export command in the terminal nothing happens

Comment: @EmaJ You dont have to run `export` command in terminal rather you have to add all these four lines to `/etc/environment` also add these lines to `~/.bashrc` . Execute `gedit ~/.bashrc` in terminal and add these four lines to it and save it.

Comment: I've run the commands and added the lines but can created any project on netbeans.

Comment: Does netbeans still throws the same error, even after restarting system?

Comment: Yes it does it always shows the same exception

Comment: Then it is probably a bug, you may file it at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ And you may use eclipse alternatively